# How To insert records of one database to other database in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 database with tables.

I wanted to insert records from first database to second database table in LINQ. I have created 2 dbml files with 2 datacontexts but I am unable to code the insertion of records.

I have list of records:

```
using(_TimeClockDataContext)
{
    var Query = (from EditTime in _TimeClockDataContext.tblEditTimes
                 orderby EditTime.ScanDate ascending
                 select new EditTimeBO
                 {
                     EditTimeID = EditTime.EditTimeID,
                     UserID = Convert.ToInt64(EditTime.UserID),
                     ScanCardId = Convert.ToInt64(EditTime.ScanCardId),
                 }).ToList();
    return Query;
}
```

Now I want to insert record in new table which is in `_Premire2DataContext`.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question, please read the rules first. Could you please provide an example of your code and an explanation of what in that code is not working such an an error message? thanks.

Comment: I have list of records :

Comment: If its linq2sql, call `_TimeClockDataContext.SubmitChanges()`.

Comment: No i want records of list which i am getttig from above coding . want to insert this list to the new database having table x. how to write query for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "copy" records from one database to another using Linq then you need two database contexts, one for the database you are reading from, and one for the database you are reading to.

```
EditTime[] sourceRows;
using (var sourceContext = CreateSourceContext())
{
    sourceRows = ReadRows(sourceContext);
}

using (var destinationContext = CreateDestinationContext())
{
    WriteRows(destinationContext, sourceRows);
}
```

You now just need to fill in the implementations for `ReadRows` and `WriteRows` using standard LINQ to SQL code. The code for writing rows should look a bit like this.

```
void WriteRows(TimeClockDataContext context, EditTime[] rows)
{
    foreach (var row in rows)
    {
        destinationContext.tblEditTimes.Add(row);
    }
    destinationContext.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Note that as long as the schema is the same you can use the same context and therefore the same objects - so when reading records we ideally want to return the correct array type, therefore reading is going to look a bit like this

```
EditTime[] ReadRows(TimeClockDataContext context)
{
    return (
        from EditTime in _TimeClockDataContext.tblEditTimes
        orderby EditTime.ScanDate ascending
        select EditTime
     ).ToArray();
}
```

You can use an array or a list - it doesn't really matter. I've used an array mostly because the syntax is shorter. Note that we return the original `EditTime` objects rather than create new ones as this means we can add those objects directly to the second data context.

I've not compiled any of this code yet, so it might contain some typos. Also apologies if I've made some obvious errors - its been a while since I last used LINQ to SQL.

If you have foreign keys or the second database has a different schema then things get more complicated, but the fundamental process remains the same - read from one context (using standard LINQ to SQL) and store the results somewhere, then add the rows the the second context (using standard LINQ to SQL).

Also note that this isn't necessarily going to be particularly quick. If performance is an issue then you should look into using bulk inserts in the `WriteRows` method, or potentially even use linked servers to do the entire thing in SQL.

Comment: Thx Justin...will try it